# Check where this.props.history.goBack() will redirect to

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Is there a way to check where this.props.history.goBack() will redirect to before it redirects? I have a button that sends the user back to the previous page, but I want to make sure it isn't taking them away from my website. Thanks!

Comment: Something that might help: [How to get previous path? · Issue #1066 · ReactTraining/react-router · GitHub](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/1066)